# Deploying VSIX using MSI installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, vsix

Can anyony help me in "How to install VSIX using MSI installer".

For msi installer I'm using visual studio Installer setup project.

When I use VSIX with extension manager it works fine.

I want to have it as a installer(using msi) instead of using enstension manager.

or any best wa yto install and unstall VSIX files

Comment: as Matt said that is not suggested way then what is the best way to install ans uninstall these vsix files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a suggested scenario.

From MSDN, "You cannot use a Windows Installer package (MSI) to deploy a VSIX package. However, you can extract the contents of a VSIX package for MSI deployment. This document shows how to prepare a project whose default output is a VSIX package for inclusion in a Setup project."

Here are some pages with more information:

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332502.aspx)

[VS Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/27/vsix-and-msi.aspx)

[MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/b6b06bff-5464-4bff-8ffb-66bbae6debe0/)

---

Adding more information about how you could accomplish this:

You can't use the vsix itself, but you can unzip it (just rename the vsix to zip) and add all of the files to your MSI manually.  As it says on the [VS Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/27/vsix-and-msi.aspx), you need to make sure that you include the vsixmanifest file (it should be in the vsix) and make sure that you set the "InstalledByMsi" property to true.  If you have a pkgdef file, make sure you include that as well.

Again, as it says on the [VS Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/27/vsix-and-msi.aspx), all of these files should be installed to

```
"%VSInstallDir%\Common7\Ide\Extensions\Your Company\Your Product\Version"
```

(And you'll need to replace %VSInstallDir% based on the actual location.)

You asked:

> How to put some files in non special folders using visual studio installer.

Vsix packages installed by the standard vsix installer will always put all of the files under the same folder in "%VSInstallDir%\Common7\Ide\Extensions...", but because you're using an MSI, you should be able to put other files in other places if you want.

I haven't tried this myself, but I've worked with vsix quite a bit.

I hope this helps!

Comment: in VS Blog 4th point says drop those in visual studio directory.How to put some files in non special folders using visual studio installer.

Comment: What do you mean by Visual Studio installer? Do you mean msi?

Answer (score 0):

in my case i needed to run devenv /setup in admin mode in order to work, then it work perfect !

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup